# How to Kill application running on background while using other application on button click in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, background, kill

My application launches the Google Maps App for tracking. But when the Google Maps app completes its tracking. I used the push notification on which the user tap and it get back its own application. But the Google Maps app goes to background and it remains in background unless we forcefully kill the application.
So I want when the user get back its application, the Google Maps Application should kill and will not remains on background.

Comment: There is no provision to kill google maps application from your application. User have to kill google map application manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't kill other apps. Full stop. Apple would never allow that. Their app sandbox prevents you from affecting other processes on the device.

(On a jailbroken device you probably could.)